# Code not passing all test cases

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I was trying to solve the following question:

You are playing a game in which you have a rectangular grid of n*n cells. Each cell is either empty or has a firework. 
Empty cells are marked with ".", cells with firework are marked with "*" . 
Two cells are said to be adjacent if they share a side.

If firework in any cell explodes it destroys itself and the empty cells connected to it. 
Two cells are connected if there is a path of empty adjacent cells between them.
You have to find the number of cells that will be destroyed if the fireworks are triggered independently.
Input Constraints:
1≤n≤1000
Sample Input
4

* . . *

. . * .

* . . *

* . . *

Sample Output
66(9(for 1st *)+10+10+9+10+9+9(for 7th *)).

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdio>
#define n 1001
using namespace std;
///char arr[1001][1001];
bool is_valid(int x,int y,int n1){
    if(x<0||y<0||x>=n1||y>=n1){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
int cal_(int i,int j,char arr[n][n],int n1){
    pair<int,int> p(i,j);
    queue<pair<int,int> > q;
    //for()
    q.push(p);
    int ans_ = 0;
    //visited
    bool visited[n1][n1] = {{0}};
    //visited[][]
    int diff[][2] = {{-1,0},{0,1},{1,0},{0,-1}};
    while(!q.empty()){
        pair<int,int> curr = q.front();
        q.pop();
        int x = curr.first;
        int y = curr.second;
        //cout<<"x and y"<<x<<" "<<y<<endl;
        visited[x][y] = 1;
        for(int k=0;k< 4;k++){
            int newx = x + diff[k][0];
            int newy = y + diff[k][1];
            //cout<<newx<<" "<<newy<<" arr->"<<" "<<arr[newx][newy]<<endl;
            if(is_valid(newx,newy,n1)){
                    if( arr[newx][newy] == '.' && visited[newx][newy] == 0){
                        visited[newx][newy] = 1;
                        //cout<<newx<<" "<<newy<<endl;
                        ans_++;
                        pair<int,int> p(newx,newy);
                        q.push(p);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    //cout<<ans_+1<<endl;
    //if(ans_!=0)
        return ans_+1;
    //else
      //  return 0;
}
int main(){
    //cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int n1;
    //char arr[n][n];
    //char arr_copy[n][n];
    cin>>n1;
//    rtrt = n1;
    char arr[n][n];
    char arr_copy[n][n];
    //scanf("%d",&n1);
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n1;j++){
            char ch;
            cin>>ch;
            //fflush(stdin);
            //scanf(" %c",&ch);
            arr[i][j] = ch;
            arr_copy[i][j] = ch;
        }
    }
    if(n1 == 1){
        cout<<0;
        //printf("0");
        return 0;
    }
    int ans_ = 0;
        for(i=0;i<n1;i++){
            for(j=0;j<n1;j++){
                if(arr[i][j] == '*'){
                   // flag = 1;
                    ans_ += cal_(i,j,arr_copy,n1);
                    //arr[i][j] = '-';
                    //cout<<1<<" ";
                }
            }
        }
    cout<<ans_;
    //printf("%d",ans_);
    //cal_(arr,)
    return 0;
}
```

I simply applied a BFS and added individual sum.The problem is that it only passed some test cases,wrong answer and time limit exceeded in some.Can some please suggest what test case am I missing in handling?

Comment: why a -1,isn't the question following all the rules specified by stack overflow?

Comment: I didn't -1, but it's expected that you describe the problem and provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example in the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Just showing your code and saying that it failed some test cases isn't sufficient (or equivalently, asking for test cases which cause the program to fail). The question should be closed for that reason, but it also may attract downvotes for "not showing research effort" where here research means debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

- calculate connected areas of empty cells and count the number of cells in each area
- for each firework cell determine the adjacent areas and sum their counts (+1 for firework cell itself)

Comment: how to implement the first point?Is it possible with just 1 BFS traversal?

Comment: BFS from first empty cell, then find another cell not marked by the first BFS and do BFS from that one etc. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)